# align 4 columns using the bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, multiple-columns

I have this code

```
<div class="panel-body">   
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="head6">Business Name : </label><span class="head9">'.$name.'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="head6">Website URL : </label><span class="head9">'.$url.'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="head6">Tagline : </label><span class="head9">'.$tagline.'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="head6">Description : </label><span class="head9">'.$descrip.'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="head6">Business Email : </label><span class="head9">'.$bemail.'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="head6">Address : </label><span class="head9">'.$address.'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="head6">City : </label><span class="head9">'.$city.'</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

that basically looks like this

[image]

what i want is to indent the variable to the right aligned to each other using the grid system so that it would maintain its responsiveness when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

add bootstrap predefined `pull-right` selector to all `<span class="head9">` like `<span class="head9 pull-right">`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3bzx906/)

OR

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="halfL">
    <label class="head6">Business Email : </label>
  </div>
  <div class="halfR">
    <span class="head9">'.$bemail.'</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your css

```
.halfL{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.halfR{
  width:50%;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: its too close to the right div... how can i adjust it a little bit to the left

Comment: it goes to the right but its does not align from the left, and its too far right even if your increase the padding.

Comment: @Shehary never actually used `pull-right` before, thanks for that, it is also the better solution I believe

Comment: @li0n_za, I was just passing through and saw your effort trying to help the OP so thought to give you a hand instead posting another answer,.

Comment: i got another problem .. its not mobile responsive :(

Comment: use the 1st solution mentioned in the answer and it should be 100% mobile responsive

Answer (score 0):

```
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="head6">Business Name : </label><span class="head9">'.$name.'</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="head6">Website URL : </label><span class="head9">'.$url.'</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="head6">Tagline : </label><span class="head9">'.$tagline.'</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="head6">Description : </label><span class="head9">'.$descrip.'</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="head6">Business Email : </label><span class="head9">'.$bemail.'</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="head6">Address : </label><span class="head9">'.$address.'</span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <label class="head6">City : </label><span class="head9">'.$city.'</span>
                </div>
```